# How to transpose from guitar scores to clarinet?

Tags: guitar, chords, transposition, transcription, clarinet

- Guitar in standard tuning
- B♭ clarinet

I have the chords for a song in guitar. I need to join the guitar on clarinet, but I cannot find the partiture to play.

How can I join the guitar (rhythmic guitar) on clarinet using the chords he is playing?

I mean what is the analogue of it in clarinet?
By the way the song is **Volare by gypsy kings**. So if you know the partitures that would be awesome.

Comment: Are you the clarinettist? Do you need the _clarinet_ part?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I find composing for transposing instruments hard](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/74774/i-find-composing-for-transposing-instruments-hard)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - there's a tenuous link, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clarinet most used is a *transposing* instrument, in B♭. That means when the music shows a note C, and the player blows what he perceives as that note, the pitch comes out as a B♭. So everything he plays off the partitions will be a whole tone lower than you need on guitar. See a C chord - play a B♭, see a G chord - play an F, and so on.

There are other clarinets, but B♭ is the most commonly used, and written for.

You *could* capo the guitar, but at the 10th fret, it's not particularly practical.

What we don't do on this site is provide music, or routes to that music, sorry.

**EDIT**  - just in case I read the question the wrong way round. You'll have to play the clarinet part a whole tone higher. So: see a C, play a D, see a G, play an A, etc. Or, re-write it all in a key that's a tone higher.

When I was learning trumpet, (also B♭) a long time ago, I realised the same problem, and learned to read 'properly', but also 'wrongly' - playing a tone above what was written. That put my playing into the same key as everyone else, rather than have everyone else change to match my key.

**RE-EDIT**- playing only one note at a time on clarinet (usual!) you could even play the melody - which would be, as I say, a tone higher than that if it was written for a concert - tuned instrument. If you could find the partition written for clarinet, then you'd play verbatim.Or- if you wanted to extemporise around the tune, just need to be aware that the key you'd do that in is the guitarist's key - a tone above.

**RE-RE-EDIT** - there are plenty of arrangements available for not a lot, most if not all can be transposed before buying. All you need do is ascertain what key the singer or guitarist wants to do the song in, and order the same but in a key a tone higher. That way, you'll be able to read off as the others play, and all be in the same key!

Comment: Got it. What about the chord like Em B7

Comment: Like I say, drop every chord a whole tone. So Em>Dm, and B7>A7. It seems a little strange that any chords written for guitar wouldn't be in *concert pitch*, though.

Comment: When I read the OP's question I got the impression he himself was the clarinettist. I could be wrong.

Comment: I got it. One tone higher for clarinet. I dont get how to play E minor, I mean it is a chord, in clarinet I just play singles notes, so which note should I play when the guitar plays E minor. should I play D in clarinet? The chord of Dm is formed by three singles notes, which note(s) should I play on clarinet. I am so sorry I just learnt how to read notes like two weeks ago, but I am very motivated. thanks for your explanations

Comment: @OldBrixtonian yes your are right. I need to play a tone higher that what is written for guitar

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - thanks, answer edited accordingly. But OP seems to have the gist anyway - except trying to play chords on clarinet..!

Comment: When the guitar plays an Em chord, you play any notes of the F#m chord: F#, A, C#. When it plays B7, you play notes of the C#7 chord: C#, E#, G#, B. Get it? :-)

Comment: @Tim: Sorry to galumph in. I was worried he might set off for the gig :-)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - you mean leaving the clarinet at home and picking up a guitar instead..?

Comment: No! Taking his clarinet, and sounding TWO tones lower than the guitar!